# How to make a looping for input data then sum all value without override the first input

Tags: java, loops

My professor asked me to make a program about cashier using Java. The program is supposed to be inputting the codename of the product and how much you buy it.

Before printing the value, the program will ask you "do you want to count another [Y/N]". If the user inputting `Y` then the user will asked to input another value. And then the program will sum every inputs as a total and print it.

I'm almost successful in making the program, but I don't know how to make loop for inputting another value without override the first value. And then I can sum total value each input. As I know using for loops makes you to set the value of maximum loops, before starting loops.

And this is what I'm trying to do

```
for(i=0; i<x; i++){
  System.out.println("KODE BUAH (A/J/M):");
  kode = input.nextLine();
  if (kode.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
  {   harga = harga+47000;
      nama = nama+"Anggur";
  } 
  if (kode.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
  {   harga = harga+30000;
      nama = nama+"Jeruk";
  } 
  if (kode.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
  {   harga = harga+20000;
      nama = nama+"Melon";
  }
  while (!(kode.equals("a") || kode.equals("j") || kode.equals("m"))){
      System.out.println("INPUT SALAH");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("KODE BUAH   (A/J/M):");
      kode = input.nextLine();
  }
  System.out.print("JUMLAH BELI :");
  jml = input.nextInt();
  
  bayar = harga*jml;
  if (bayar > 300000)
  {
    diskon = bayar/10;
  }
  else diskon = 0;
    
  bayar = harga*jml;
  do {
    System.out.println("masukkan Y/T");
    a = input.nextLine();
  } while (!a.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !a.equalsIgnoreCase("T"));

  } while (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
  {   
      x = x+1;
  }
```

Comment: Your indentation and use of braces is quite inconsistent. Proper and consistent formatting helps a lot in spotting control flow mistakes

Comment: 1) `while (a.equalsIgnoreCase("A"));` I think you want to remove that `;` there. 2) For your particular case you would want to move the code for reading every new item to a brand new method, then every time the user types `Y` call that method. 3) If you still need help, post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Shopping {
private Map<String, Integer> costMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, Integer> buyMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();

private void init() {
    costMap.put("A", 47000);
    costMap.put("J", 30000);
    costMap.put("M", 20000);
    
    nameMap.put("A", "Anggur");
    nameMap.put("J", "Jeruk");
    nameMap.put("M", "Melon");
    
    costMap.keySet()
           .stream()
           .forEach(k -> buyMap.put(k, 0));
}

public Shopping() {
    init();
}

public void shop() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Buy what (A/J/M)?");
            
            String code = in.readLine().toUpperCase();
            if (nameMap.containsKey(code)) {
                System.out.println("How many?");
                int amt = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                buyMap.put(code, amt + buyMap.get(code));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a valid code.");
            }
            System.out.println("Do you wish to buy more? (Y/N)");
            String doMore = in.readLine();
            if (doMore.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}

public void output() {
    int total = 0;
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : buyMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s (%d) at %d each", nameMap.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue(), costMap.get(entry.getKey())));
        total += entry.getValue() * costMap.get(entry.getKey());
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Total: %d", total));
}
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    Shopping shopping = new Shopping();
    shopping.shop();
    shopping.output();
    
}
```

}

Comment: wow really really thanks. I'm totally a beginner. And didn't even know how to use the void function before. Your code looks so clean. But I still don't understand many things. You just gave me new knowledge for me to learn more. I really appreciate this